# Excel query with dynamic cell value

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I need some help organizing what needs to be done.
I have a list of stock ticker symbols and need to download data for each one of them to be displayed in a query table. Here's what it would look like even though it is a shorten version :

[image]

I have built a url for a web query, but since my ticker changes for each request, I don't know how to have the query look into the ticker cell (C2, G2, etc...) I can do it if I name these cells, but do I have to name each one of them ? Is there a way to look at the cell value based on cell reference ?
In the example below, it would have to be at
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(meurl1 )),    where I would ad meurl1&C2 or something like that.
Any idea ?

```
let
meurl1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="meurl1"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(meurl1 )),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"date", "close", "high", "low", "open"}, {"Column1.date", "Column1.close", "Column1.high", "Column1.low", "Column1.open"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1",{{"Column1.date", type datetime}}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Column1.date", "Date"}, {"Column1.close", "Close"}, {"Column1.high", "High"}, {"Column1.low", "Low"}, {"Column1.open", "Open"}}),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Date", Order.Descending}})
```

in

Comment: As far as I know, when using `Excel.CurrentWorkbook`, you can only refer to named ranges (including tables). Meaning you can't use `C2` (or `G2`, etc) in your query code, as Power Query can't interpret arbitrary cell references/addresses.

Comment: Some options: #1 Turn the tickers in column A into a named range, then have Power Query grab the entire named range at once and loop over its values to get each ticker's data. However, this would load as one table containing all tickers' data (as opposed to a separate table for each ticker). #2 Alternatively, turn `C2` (and `G2`, etc) into named ranges and then create a query for each ticker. This would be take time/effort to do manually (especially if you need to add/remove tickers later), so maybe use VBA to automate query creation/deletion/refresh.

Comment: Thanks ! I think you understand exactly what I am facing. Option #1, I do not have the knowledge to do that. Would that be through a VBA. How do you loop it ? And Option #2 is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I have over 100 tickers. At least I know now what the options are. Would you be able to provide a very simple example of what you suggest in options 1 ?

Comment: Yes, have provided a simple example of option #1. The table should have the data you want, just not in the structure/format your question asked for.

Answer (score 0):

The example below will load data for all tickers in a single table -- and not a separate table per ticker.

1. Create a named range called `tickers` in your Excel file, which contains all tickers ( that you need to get data for) in a single column.
2. Copy-paste the code below into the Advanced Editor in Power Query -- and then see if it gives you expected output.

I've included three examples (`verticalTable`, `horizontalTable` and `anotherHorizontalTable`). See which one of the three works best for you and your data.

I'm not sure what the value of `meurl1` is in your file, so I've just copy-pasted it from your question.

---

```
let
    tickers = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tickers"]}[Content][Column1],
    url = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="meurl1"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    getTickerData = (someTicker as text) as table => 
        let
            response = Web.Contents(url & someTicker),
            parsed = Json.Document(response),
            toTable = Table.FromRecords(parsed, type table [
                date = datetime, open = number, high = number, low = number, close = number
            ])
        in toTable,
    // This approach should stack your ticker data vertically.
    // It's not what you asked for, but it might be a bit quicker than the approaches below.
    verticalTable = 
        let
            looped = List.Transform(tickers, each [ticker = _, data = getTickerData(ticker)]),
            toTable = Table.FromRecords(looped, type table [ticker = text, data = record]),
            expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(toTable, "data", {"date", "open", "high", "low", "close"}, {"Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close"})
        in expanded,
    // This approach will stack your ticker data horizontally, but with all tickers sharing a single
    // Date column.
    horizontalTable = 
        let
            allData = List.Transform(tickers, each [ticker = _, data = getTickerData(ticker)]),
            uniqueDates = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(allData, each [data][date]))),
            looped = List.Accumulate(
                allData,
                Table.FromColumns({uniqueDates}, type table [Date = datetime]),
                (tableState as table, tickerData as record) as table =>
                    let
                        columnsToExpand = List.RemoveItems(Table.ColumnNames(tickerData[data]), {"date"}),
                        joined = Table.NestedJoin(tableState, "Date", tickerData[data], "date", "_toExpand"),
                        expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(joined, "_toExpand", columnsToExpand, List.Transform(columnsToExpand, each tickerData[ticker] & " (" & Text.Proper(_) & ")"))
                    in expanded
            )
        in looped,
    // This approach will stack your ticker data horizontally, but the difference here is each ticker
    // will have its own Date column.
    anotherHorizontalTable = 
        let
            looped = List.Accumulate(
                tickers,
                {},
                (tableColumns as list, ticker as text) as list =>
                    let
                        tickerTable = getTickerData(ticker),
                        renamed = Table.TransformColumnNames(tickerTable, each ticker & " (" & Text.Proper(_) & ")"),
                        columnNames = Table.ColumnNames(renamed),
                        columns = Table.ToColumns(renamed),
                        columnsWithMeta = List.Transform(List.Positions(columns), each columns{_} meta [columnName = columnNames{_}]),
                        combined = tableColumns & columnsWithMeta
                    in combined
            ),
            toTable = Table.FromColumns(looped, List.Transform(looped, each Value.Metadata(_)[columnName]))
        in toTable
in
    anotherHorizontalTable
```

Comment: Thanks chilin ! I will have to try that one and will get back if I am succesful